# Typing || on my keyboard

Tags: keyboard

I want to know how I can write those two lines `||` in Eclipse and/or in Android studio. I never figured out how to do this i always copied them out of the internet- -> very uncomfortable.

Comment: What sort of keyboard do you have?

Comment: When you press `Shift` and ``\`` key what do you get?

Comment: When you press AltGr+6 you will get `|` So do that twice :-)

Comment: Without seeing what keyboard you are using we can't help you. Maybe take a picture of your keyboard so we could see which key is where and post link to it. Also it can be possible that you will need to change your keyboard settings.

Comment: This question is about typing a symbol using a keyboard. It has nothing to do with java or eclipse or anything programming-related (I removed all those tags). It doesn't belong on SO. Maybe on superuser.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about typing a symbol using a keyboard.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisCorbett I am not sure if this question is appropriate for superuser as it is written now. Maybe if OP would include more informations about type of keyboard, system, keyboard settings then we could try migrating it, but as it states now I doubt that it belongs to any SE site.

Comment: I've got a standard German Keyboard(https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/German_keyboard_layout). I'm currently on Ubuntu 14.04 if you want to know that..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That depends on your keyboard. On mine it is on the key on the lower left next to the left shift.

However if you don't find it, hold the <kbd>Alt</kbd> key and type 124 on the numerical keypad. At least under Windows that returns `|`.

Comment: Yep, helped me. On German keyboards you have to hold the "Alt Gr" key and then the key next to the left shift key as you said.